# How to set rate limit on AWS Lambda function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I want to set the **rate limit** on the number of times Lambda function get called. For this I have used environ variable "`max_rate_limit`" as `0` initial value in Lambda config, however it is not able to increase the value of `max_rate_limit` as lambda function called.

Main objective: For example Lambda Function by name **Test** , should not get call more than 1000 times in single day.

Can you suggest any other approach besides **global variable**?

```
import json
import os
from os import environ
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    count = int(environ["max_rate_limit"])
    environ["max_rate_limit"] = str(++count)
    print(environ["max_rate_limit"])
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Comment: Have a `whatever = 0` at the top level and then `global whatever` in your function and then change the `whatever` however you like. However very unclear what the actual goal is. Do you know there may be many lambdas running at the same time, environments be reused and not reused, ... !?

Comment: Hi @luk2302 Thanks for replay, My main object is that I want to set rate lime on my lambda function :"Test". It should not call more than 1000 time in 24 hours. Can you suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: Then you need some persistent storage for that information anyway, e.g. use something like a DynamoDB to store it. This is way more complicated than it sounds at first. E.g. do you want a rolling window?

Comment: @luk2302 This sound good, to use DDB however, it will have some latency. I we are able to use environment variable somehow then it will best.

Comment: You can't use the environment for that, you can use global variables in your lambda which will be lost after 1-2 hours after the lambda execution environment is destroyed. You will have to use external persistency.

Comment: A global variable won't work where you've got multiple concurrent invocations of your Lambda. It's global in the context of that execution environment and two requests at the same time will raise two execution environments and thus different values. Persistent storage is a better approach. You could use Dynamo. If you went down the env variable route, you'd need to update your function which adds latency and there will be a delay in that being picked up... So it won't be concrete.